# What is the name/type of this kind of switch?

Tags: switches, identification, mouse

I have a Logitech T400 mouse. The left click switch began to fail and I am looking for a replacement for it.

[image]

I don't know what the name/type is of this kind of switch, so I can't search for a new one, preferably of the same high quality.

Why not just buy another mouse? Because I simply love the [Logitech T400](https://www.logitech.com/assets/46474/zone-touch-mouse-t400.pdf)'s unique design, and it isn't available anymore in the market.

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=surface+mount+tact+switch&iar=images&iax=images&ia=images

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are generally known as **Tactile Switches**, as they have a haptic feedback click.

An example here [Yellow Button Tactile Switch, SPST 50 mA @ 24 V dc 0.55mm](https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/tactile-switches/0183717)

You need to match dimensions, but shouldn't have problems finding an exact replacement as sizes are standardized.

I've personally used Omron switches for decades in industrial uses, and they have very good reliability.  Other suppliers are also available.